# How to install odoo in ubuntu 14.04? What is basic requirements for develop odoo module like html,css etc

Tags: odoo, odoo-10, odoo-11, odoo-12

**I am a beginner for ODOO.**

**Question #1)** What is technical requirements for develop ODOO module?
**Question #2)** Minimum Hardware requirements for ODOO software?
**Question #3)** How to start learning ODOO?
**Question #4)** Which is the best tutorial for learning ODOO?

**My system specification,**
Processor - Intel® Core™2 Duo CPU E7500 @ 2.93GHz × 2
RAM - 8 GB
OS Type - 32 bit

Answer (score 2):

**Q1 ==>>** knowledge of python & xml languages, postgresql, good programming basics

**Q2 ==>>**  4 GB Ram,  4 CPU, Hard disk 100 GB will be enough (but it depends if you are taking database backup every day in the same instance.), chek this link for more informations : https://www.odoo.com/documentation/11.0/setup/deploy.html#worker-number-calculation.

**Q3 ==>** check this link: https://www.quora.com/What-are-the-best-resources-to-learn-Odoo-for-beginners.

**Q4 ==>** 
https://odorials.com/tutorials/general/how-to-start-using-odoo/

http://www.erpish.com/odoo/step-by-step-tutorial-for-how-to-create-a-hello-world-application-for-odoo/

https://www.odoo.com/documentation/11.0/howtos/backend.html

https://www.odoo.com/documentation/

***don't forget that practice and mistakes are the best teachers***